# How can I create a tkinter Python chat app with msg feature?

Tags: python, tkinter, msg

I want to create a Python chat app with [msg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msg) feature.

Well, I've been working on this project for a while, and I want to build a messaging app using Python tkinter with [msg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msg) feature available in any PC.

**The problem is that the code contains some errors.**

Now I will show you the code

```
from threading import *
from tkinter import *
import os


window = Tk()
window.title("msg")
window.geometry("350x150+300+100")


txtYourMessage = Entry(window, width=50)
txtYourMessage.insert(0,"")
txtYourMessage.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

server = Entry(window, width=50)
server.insert(0,"")
server.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)


def Message():
    os.system("msg * /server:%server% %txtYourMessage%")

btnSendMessage = Button(window, text="Send", width=20, command=Message)
btnSendMessage.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

**When I run the code, the code actually works but it doesn't send the message you wrote, I think the problem is in this part**

```
txtYourMessage = Entry(window, width=50)
txtYourMessage.insert(0,"")
txtYourMessage.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

server = Entry(window, width=50)
server.insert(0,"")
server.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)


def Message():
    os.system("msg * /server:%server% %txtYourMessage%")
```

Comment: Try running this - `os.system("msg * /server:%server% %txtYourMessage%")`, what do you get?

Comment: I think you need to use `os.system(f"msg * /server:{server.get()} {txtYourMessage.get()}")`.

Comment: Thank you, I will edit the question now and post the answer for everyone to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct code

```
from threading import *
from tkinter import *
import os


window = Tk()
window.title("msg")
window.geometry("350x150+300+100")


txtYourMessage = Entry(window, width=50)
txtYourMessage.insert(0,"")
txtYourMessage.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

server = Entry(window, width=50)
server.insert(0,"")
server.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)


def Message():
    os.system(f"msg * /server:{server.get()} {txtYourMessage.get()}")

btnSendMessage = Button(window, text="Send", width=20, command=Message)
btnSendMessage.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```